# Convert multiple Int to varchar in sql using IN condition

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, types

I have a two tables.

**Emp and dept**.

Emp has column deptno varchar type, and dept has column deptno int type.

When i use following query:

```
select * from emp where deptno in (select deptno from dept)
```

It does not retrieve any data because of different data type.

Is there any way to convert multiple deptno from int to varchar?

Comment: Fix your data!  Foreign keys should have the same type as the primary key and they should be declared.  The simplistic answer to your question is `cast()` or `convert()`, but the correct thing to do is fix the data.

Answer (score 1):

You can use convert

```
  select * 
  from emp 
  where CONVERT(INT, deptno) in (select deptno from dept)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select * 
from emp 
where deptno in 
      (select CAST(deptno AS Varchar(255)) AS deptno 
       from dept)
```

or make the fields the same type as they are related as per comment

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT
,tableemp.* 
,CAST(dep.deptno AS INT) deptno
FROM deptno dep
INNER JOIN emp 
emp.PK_PrimaryKey = dep.FK_ForeignKey
```

Comment: this is not valid SQL

Comment: if you cannot join two tables with the relationship u just need to do the select  and do a inner select like the guy above. I just thought since it is a SQL table it should have some relationship LIKE PK and FK's but if it is not there then do what the other guy has done above. Good luck